# Present GameScene after segue to MainMenu UIViewController in SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit game. Here I present GameScene from UIViewController (GameViewController):

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var scene: GameScene!

        let  skView = view as! SKView

        skView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false

        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
        skView.showsPhysics = true
        skView.showsFPS = true

        scene.segueViewController = self
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

It works fine only then I create GameScene for first time. After game is finished player redirected in MainMenu (UIViewController). If I try to present GameViewController again, my game crashes:

Errors:

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
>         5 ->  0x1110b1fce <+10>: jae    0x1110b1fd8               ; <+20> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
>
> UIKit`UIApplicationMain:
>
> 47 -> 0x112fb05d6 <+159>: movq   0x116f033(%rip), %rbx     ; (void
>   *)0x0000000111fa9cc0: objc_release Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
>
> 12 main:
>
> 14 -> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread
>   1: signal SIGABRT
>
> 13 start:
>
> libdyld.dylib`start: 3 ->    0x115f47d81 <+1>: movl   %eax, %edi
>   Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the complete and exact error message and clearly point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: As you asked...

Comment: That aside I believe that from what you stated because it is an issue with the second time, you might want to check where you leave and if you have accidentally made it so that when you leave you mess up the view controller making it so that when you try to go to it from the other view you aren’t pointing to something that it thinks doesn’t exist